# appbundle and split crash on start android flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-install-apk

So I recently deployed my appbundle on Google Play store which was working fine up until I released update I get crash on start every time..I tried with different API then I tried split per abi same issue it does not work...
I'm not sure if it's related to digital signature or something

Weird thing generating apk `flutter run --release` work fine on local 
but I rather stick with appbundle since the apk is larger in size

I've been trying to look command to debug this no luck any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out this was caused after updating `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'` in build.gradle dependencies which requires gradle 6.1.1 to work 
I didn't notice this before because I was using

```
lintOptions {
disable 'InvalidPackage'
checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

which was causing theses errors

> Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
>   Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

So the simple solution was to downgrade the classpath to 3.6.3

Note : I'm using JDK 14 in case it helps.